# getting inner html of a link when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have an HTML Link and a p tag as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfun()">Computer Science</a>
<p id="putpara"></p>
```

This Is My Function :

```
function myfun() {
            document.getElementById("putpara").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;

        }
```

However when i click the link the content inside the `paragraph tag` changes to **undefined**.

Seems like a silly mistake i am making.....Newbie to javascript....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to send `this` parameter in your function like this:

**html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfun(this)">Computer Science</a>
<p id="putpara"></p>
```

**js**

```
window.myfun = function(obj) {
            document.getElementById("putpara").innerHTML = obj.innerHTML;
}
```

`this` refers to the DOM element.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/62UGs/4/)

Comment: The OP doesn't really *have* to send *this*, but it's certainly a good option. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`this` in `myfun` in your sample, refers to the global object, which in this case would be the `Window`-object.

You can fix it like this, provided you give your `a`-tag the ID `link`:

```
function myfun() {
    document.getElementById("putpara").innerHTML = document.getElementById("link").innerHTML;
}
```

If you want to learn more on why you experienced this problem, you should read up on Closures in JavaScript.

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out in a comment to my answer, a more reusable solution would be to change the HTML to this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfun(this)">Computer Science</a>
```

In this case, the `onclick`-event will be called with the corresponding DOM-element as a parameter.

Then change the JavaScript-function, so that it accepts the passed in element:

```
function myfun(element) {
    document.getElementById("putpara").innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Or maybe `event.target.innerHTML` if the code needs to be re-usable for multiple links.

Comment: I would add cleaner solution: function myfun(el) { document.getElementById("putpara").innerHTML = el.innerHTML; }, and "<a onclick="myfun(this)">

Comment: yea exactly the solution i was looking for was found in the comment

Comment: @Zentoaku pls put this as an answer...so that other people may benefit

Comment: I have added the suggested solution to my answer.

Comment: "*this refers to the enclosing function, meaning myfun*" Not at all, it will be the global/window object. It also has nothing to do with closures.

Comment: @RobG That would depend on how the function is invoked.

Comment: @kaspermoerch—you stated "*in your sample*", so it's known how the function is called.

Comment: @RobG I see now that I was mistaken. Thank you for correction my mistake. I have updated my answer to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfun(this)">Computer Science</a>
<p id="putpara"></p>

function myfun(obj) {
            document.getElementById("putpara").innerHTML = obj.innerHTML;

        }
```

Comment: Code–only answers are not that helpful, you need to explain why the OP didn't work as expected and why yours does.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this maybe:

```
function myfun() {
    document.getElementById("putpara").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

Or like this(if it's not inside onload or ready function):

```
window.myfun = function() {
    document.getElementById("putpara").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

**Explanation:**

`event.target` pretty much returns the object on which the event was dispatched on. According to MDN:

> This property of event objects is the object the event was dispatched
>   on. It is different than event.currentTarget when the event handler is
>   called in bubbling or capturing phase of the event.

And:

> The event.target property can be used in order to implement event
>   delegation.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aLvev/)